# Information retrieval / slot filling / NLP

Tags: nlp, information-retrieval

Excuse if this has been answered before.

I need to extract features and parse from a piece of text and run some analysis. For e.g. "Plot the past 5-year sales of Apple" should give me the following

Information:

- Company: Apple
- Item: Sales
- Period: past 5 years
- Action: Plot

What deep learning techniques / algorithms should I be looking to use?

Any pointers are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually handled as a two step process:

- intent detection
- slot filling

Intent detection is basically just a kind of classification. So if your program has multiple kinds of questions it can be asked you build a list of examples for each and train a classifier.

Slot filling is typically modelled as a sequence labelling problem, so you can look into seq2seq.

You can find more detailed information in any tutorial on how to make a chatbot.

Comment: Thanks polm23. I dont have a dataset for this task. Any inputs on how to create one?

Comment: Pretend you are a user of your app and make some fake data. That should be enough to get you started.